# Merge several mstest trx files into a single trx file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest

We use Visual Studio 2008 and MSTest.

We have a batch file that the developers use to get latest version, build solution, run database scripts and run all tests.

The problem is that we have many test projects. So at the end the developer must open each trx file to check if anything failed.

Is there a way to write all test results to a single trx file, or to merge the results to a single file?

Thanks

Shiraz

Comment: Shiraz, the Trx files are basic XML files and could be mashed together without too much effort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mstest /testcontainer:YourTestContainer1.dll /testcontainer:YourTestContainer2.dll ... + all the other mstest parameters you need, testrunconfig etc. leeds to one .trx file

Comment: Thanks, I did not think that you could use the /testcontainer parameter more than once :)

Comment: :( I was very hopeful with this, but it turns out you can only have one testsettings parameter set, and i have a different per solution

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if your test containers have conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when configuring a build server that can only process a single trx file with test results. Running all test assemblies at once is not always an option, e.g. I need to do unit tests, deploy my web app, and then run some UI tests on the deployed application.

I ended up merging my trx files using [TRX Merger Utility](http://trxmerger.codeplex.com/). Some people's reviews on the page suggest that it didn't work for them, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved this simply was to put all my test projects in the same solution file (need not be a solution file that is actually used by the devs), I then add a local testrun config to the solution and use file in my mstest command line instruction.

That way I only create one trx file.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have all the test projects in the same solution. But there are ca. 8 test projects, each project creates it's own trx file.

Comment: Are you running tests using mstest from command line / batch file? For each dll?

Comment: Apologies ... edited you need to add a test run config and use that in the mstest command line

Answer (score -2):

```
mstest /testcontainer:YourTestContainer1.dll    /testcontainer:YourTestContainer2.dll ...
```

is limited! Think on it, if you have a big project.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). This site is a Q&A site not a forum.